# Spring Data MongoDB - MappingMongoConverter with custom converters

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoTemplate with custom mapping converters:

```
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter"/>
    </bean>

    <mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter" >
        <mongo:custom-converters>
            <mongo:converter>
                <bean class="foo.bar.flap.MyCustomTypeToStringConverter"/>
            </mongo:converter>
            <mongo:converter>
                <bean class="foo.bar.flap.MyOtherCustomTypeConverter"/>
            </mongo:converter>
        </mongo:custom-converters>
    </mongo:mapping-converter>
```

This configuration seems to ignore JPA annotations such as @Id and @Transient.

According to [this post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/100180-transient-annotation-being-ignored-spring-mongodb-1-0-0-m2) from Oliver Gierke on the Spring forums, I need to use the MappingMongoConverter to enable this. However, I can't seem to figure out the right syntax for combining the MappingMongoConverter with the existing custom converters.

Can anyone point me to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough info.

Your `<mongo:mapping-converter>` is correct.

We don't see now an issue.

Note, Oliver made a comment for `@Id` and `@Transient` from `org.springframework.data.annotation`, not JPA.

Maybe that is a confuse for you?

Just change JPA annotation to Spring Data and you'll get it worked.

Comment: This was the answer. Thanks for the help!